# If the user has the software display "x" else "" Excel function in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, countif

I am using Microsoft Office Excel 2010 and want to semi-automate a table by use of a function. I have made a test version to explain the problem.

I have a list with users and their software underneath their name.
[image: Person with software underneath]

Now do I want a table to fill with `x` or stay blank `""` if the person has the software or not.
[image: Final Table with x or ""]

The code I have right now is:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(TestAll!A:A;A2;TestAll!A:A;B1)>0;"x";"")
```

Could someone see a way how to improve this code/function to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified example: (I just used one sheet so I can show it all in one screenshot)

```
= IF(COUNTIF(INDEX($J:$M;0;MATCH($A2;$J$1:$M$1;0));B$1)>0;"x";"")
```

The only difference in your case is that `J:M` would be `A:D` on a different sheet, e.g. `$J:$M` would be `TestAll!$A:$D` and `$J$1:$M$1` would be `TestAll!$A$1:$D$1`.

Put this formula in cell `B2` and drag it over and down to cell `G5`.

See below.

[image]